# Не переведены подсказки при наведении в панели модератора

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, инструменты-модератора

При наведении на комментарий, на который поставили флаг:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При наведение на количество тревог:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На странице метки:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/7757

Предложил:

> Нажмите для редактирования напрямую

У второго вроде есть переводы в традусёре, но в интерфейсе не вижу их:

https://ru.traducir.win/string/3794
https://ru.traducir.win/string/3795
https://ru.traducir.win/string/3796

https://ru.traducir.win/string/9800

Предложил:

> Объединить эту метку с другой

Comment: Кстати, теперь у Вас есть права на утверждение строк в традусёре, как у ромбоноса :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ есть, но лучше пускай этим будете вы заниматься, т.к. я могу накосячить )

Comment: любой может накосячить :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а вы ведь все строки видите? И из админки тоже?

Comment: строки любой видит. Но интерфейс только избранные :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ очень многих ключей нету в трансе вообще )= Буду постепенно на мете просить добавить.

Comment: значит, можно на MSE репортить, чтоб добавили.